# Why is Selenium causing a CSRF 403?

Tags: django, selenium, cookies, csrf, django-csrf

I'm trying to create a simple login test using Django and Selenium, but getting a 403 due to a CSRF failure. I'm expecting the middleware to add the cookie on the GET request and then parse it back out on the POST.

Here's what I've checked so far:

**1. Is the cookie being set on the GET request to `/accounts/login/`?**

> Yes, the cookie is being set in the `process_response` method

**2. Is the cookie available on the Selenium driver?**

> Yes

```
ipdb> self.selenium.get_cookies()
[{u'domain': u'localhost', u'name': u'csrftoken', u'value': u'DzNbEn9kZw0WZQ4OsRLouriFN5MOIQos', u'expiry': 1470691410, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': False, u'secure': True}]
```

**3. Is the cookie found during the POST request?**

> No, this try/except from `django.middleware.CsrfViewMiddleware.process_view` fails:

[source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/middleware/csrf.py#L108%20link%20to%20source)

```
try:
    csrf_token = _sanitize_token(
        request.COOKIES[settings.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME])
    # Use same token next time
    request.META['CSRF_COOKIE'] = csrf_token
except KeyError:
    csrf_token = None
    # Generate token and store it in the request, so it's
    # available to the view.
    request.META["CSRF_COOKIE"] = _get_new_csrf_key()
```

**Code**

```
class TestLogin(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.selenium = getattr(webdriver, settings.SELENIUM_WEBDRIVER)()
        cls.selenium.maximize_window()
        cls.selenium.implicitly_wait(5)

        super(TestLogin, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()

        super(TestLogin, cls).tearDownClass()

    def test_login(self):

        self.selenium.get('{}{}'.format(self.live_server_url, '/accounts/login/?next=/'))
        assert "Django" in self.selenium.title
        un_el = self.selenium.find_element_by_id('id_username').send_keys('the_un')
        pw_el = self.selenium.find_element_by_id('id_password')
        pw_el.send_keys('the_pw')
        pw_el.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        try:
            WebDriverWait(self.selenium, 5).until(EC.title_contains("New Title"))
        except TimeoutException as e:
            msg = "Could not find 'New Title' in title. Current title: {}".format(self.selenium.title)
            raise TimeoutException(msg)
        finally:
            self.selenium.quit()
```

**Question**

What can I try next to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oldish question, but after getting stuck with this for a few hours the answer was simple.

From the [docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/security/#ssl-https)

> If a browser connects initially via HTTP, which is the default for
>   most browsers, it is possible for existing cookies to be leaked. For
>   this reason, you should set your SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE and
>   CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE settings to True. This instructs the browser to
>   only send these cookies over HTTPS connections. Note that this will
>   mean that sessions will not work over HTTP, and the CSRF protection
>   will prevent any POST data being accepted over HTTP (which will be
>   fine if you are redirecting all HTTP traffic to HTTPS).

Like me, you are probably using [django_extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) + [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) for the majority of your work, and are by default running all of your local work over SSL.

If you're using `unittest` or Djangos version of it, I'd recommend that you modify these settings at test runtime, like so:

```
...
from django.conf import settings

class ProfilePagetest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        settings.CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
        settings.SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False

        self.url = reverse('clientpage:profile')
        self.username = 'name@names.com'
        self.password = 'strange decisions...'
        get_user_model().objects.create_user(self.username, self.username, self.password)
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

This should stop the CSRF validation issues.

Comment: I would use djangos override_settings decorator to ensure settings are reset after test execution.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings